# Restoring 'post' post-type via a child theme

Tags: wordpress, closures, anonymous-function

I am working with a client who has chosen a theme which looks nice but actual removes a lot of WordPress functionality. Whether or not it is deliberate, it has removed the post type of 'post'. I found the hook they used to do this but unfortunately, they added it via a closure not a callback.

Below is a sample piece from the theme:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
remove_menu_page("edit.php");
remove_menu_page("edit-comments.php");

}
```

});

The scenario is that I am creating a child theme to add back the WP functionality. The only way I can think to restore this is by adding another action that uses add_menu_page. I just don't really know how to restore it.

I may have to switch themes but they really like this one aesthetically. Guess the downside is that it reinvents the wp-admin backend. It wants us to add data through it's interface and not through the traditional 'post' and 'page' post types.

Anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I see only one solution - absolutely remove hook `admin_menu` and after do full restore (without closure). Of course, need more read and learn about hook `admin_menu` before operating.  You can start from  [remove_all_actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_actions)

Solution No.2:
If closure callback is one in parent theme you can to use simple 'closure' remover :)

```
//remove closure callback
$hooks = $wp_filter['admin_menu'][10];

foreach ($hooks as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('|^\d|', $key))
        //closure's always started from 00000....(??)
        remove_action('admin_menu', $key);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I didn't think of that but it is actually a good possibility. I guess it runs the risk of removing any other plugin or theme additions and would be a nightmare to put back. As you said, there is really only one solution and that's it. Wish the theme makers were a little less restrictive.

Comment: I just now added a second solution :)

Comment: Great, thanks. I will give that a try. I might be missing something but where did the [10] come from? How do I know it will be 10? Is that to do with default priority? 

A little rusty on regular expressions but does that mean if there is a digital (\d) we can assume its a function (as opposed to a quote)?

Again thank you for your advice and input. I really appreciate you looking into this for me :)

Comment: '10' - this is default priority (mean Order) executing of hooks. More http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Parameters

Comment: @user1522256 Hmm.. I forgot to say how to use second solution :) It's my mistake. Most clear example with small description you can see here http://pastebin.com/gLDpfCYL

Comment: Hey, that's no problem, Za Noza. I understood what you meant but thanks for the full guide. You have provided great value today. Thanks. Mark.